# Different border-color for each flexbox item

Tags: html, css

How can I add different border-color for flexbox items. The flex items will be added dynamically, 5 different border-colors has to be applied to the items. The flexbox items need to start with the border-color red, then  the next flexbox item with border-color orange, yellow, pink, green, and then start with the red and repeat the same border-color order again.

I tried nth-child but it does not start with the color red again.

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.slider > div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
  }

.slider > div:nth-child(1n+0) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(2n+0) {
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(3n+0) {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(4n+0) {
  border: 5px solid pink;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+0) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is in your `nth-child` formula. Currently, you're looking for multiples of 1, then multiples of 2, then of 3, and so on. What you want is the remainder of n when divided by 5. Here is the relevant CSS with the corrected formulas:

```css
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+1) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+2) {
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+3) {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+4) {
  border: 5px solid pink;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+5) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! very much appreciated!

Comment: It stops working when I put the slick on it. Any Idea please

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "slick".

Comment: It is a library turns it into a carousel https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: This seems outside of the scope of this question. The `nth-child` selector should work the same regardless of what library you're using with this, but maybe it's overriding some of the styling here. Maybe try using `border: 5px solid [color] !important;` instead to try to override. Otherwise, I'm not sure the specific discussion of slick is relevant here.

Comment: No when the library is applied it sees all the items as the first one .slider > div:nth-child(5n+1) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}